# RESTful API: Pagination issue

Tags: rest, core-data, pagination

I've been working on a RESTful service in the last few months and I'm having issues with pagination on the client side.

On server side, many GET requests are paginated (cursor-based).

Every resource has two common fields: "updated" and "created".

E.g. let's say I want to retrieve a list of resources

GET /resources =>

```
{
  "resources" : [
    {
        "id": 10,
        "updated" : "iso8601_date_goes_here"
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "updated" : "iso8601_date_goes_here"
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "updated" : "iso8601_date_goes_here"
    }
  ],
  "pagination" : {
    "before": 11,
    "after": 7
  }
}
```

Resources are sorted by "updated" field.

Navigating through "windows" (I called them like that, as they're not pages) is rather easy.

Also, retrieving new resources is trivial thanks to the "created"/"updated" fields.

The question is:

How can I notify the client that a resource has been deleted?

Our iOS app relies on Core Data.

After the JSON response is parsed, we create Core Data objects and then we display those via NSFetchResultController/UICollectionView combination.

P.S. What we're trying to avoid is to invalidate the whole set of data.

Thanks for your help, and have a fantastic rest of the year.

Comment: What options have you considered? What are the pros and cons of each?